# recreate database (erased by mistake) in Symfony - Doctrine?

Tags: database, doctrine, symfony

i erased my database by mistake in phpmyadmin, i wanted to erase a table, but the whole thing has been erased. (i'm on symfony2) so i tried many things in the terminal :

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:create
[PDOException]                                     
  SQLSTATE[42000] [1049] Unknown database 'symfony'


php symfony doctrine:create-db
Could not open input file: symfony


php symfony doctrine:build --all
Could not open input file: symfony
```

but i can't manage to re-create the database, is there any way to do this?

Otherwise, i'll recreate a bundle etc. from the beginning, but if there's any other way...

Thanks

Comment: php symfony refers to symfony1 command line too. ``php app/console list`` shows a list of all commands. I guess you have to create the datbase yourself and then use symfony to populate it.

Comment: @Boo : GREAT! thanks it worked, it's usually the simplest that works, but thanks! can you put an official answer? thanks again

Answer (score 4):

Run this command:

```
php app/console doctrine:database:create
```

Then you can now create your tables:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:create
```